# Add the sum of the total amount from the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In this sheet the total amount should be sum of fuel + surge + delivery_charge should be added in Total amount column.
[image]

Ex:
1st order = 456777 this should add 109.49+303.41+25966.51 = 26379.41
2nd order = 23213213 should add 10+11318+65 = 11393

```
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, rng As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then
        rng = Cells(i, "A").End(xlDown).Row - 1
        Cells(i, "B").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C" & i & ":C" & rng), Range("E" & i & ":E" & rng), Range("G" & i & ":G" & rng))
    End If
Next i
```

I get:
[image]

But the issue is for 2nd order id. It should take only that row. But it is taking 5th and 6th row for addition.
2nd order id= 23213213 total_amt should be 11393.

Comment: Please do not include code in comments. They cannot be properly formatted there.

Comment: Hey Guys please find the code :- Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, rng As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then
rng = Cells(i, "A").End(xlDown).Row - 1
Cells(i, "B").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C" & i & ":C" & rng), Range("E" & i & ":E" & rng), Range("G" & i & ":G" & rng))
End If
Next i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in how you find `rng`.

```
rng = Cells(i, "A").End(xlDown).Row - 1
```

You're using `xlDown` to find the start of the next block of data. This works as you'd expect, except where the data changes every cell. If you click on cell A5 and press CTRL-Shift-Down, you'll see that it selects three cells as it jumps to the end of that block of data (A7). This is normal Excel behaviour.

You could re-write your code to loop through all the data until it finds the right scenario, but in this case I believe the single cell issue can just be trapped with the right `If` statement.

```
If Cells(i + 1, "A") <> "" Then rng = i
```

Try this:

```
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, rng As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then
        rng = Cells(i, "A").End(xlDown).Row - 1
        If Cells(i + 1, "A") <> "" Then rng = i
        Cells(i, "B").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C" & i & ":C" & rng), Range("E" & i & ":E" & rng), Range("G" & i & ":G" & rng))
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Watch out for the final row. It's actually summing `G7:G1048575`. This is fine if there is nothing below the table, but if there's a chance that there is something then you could also have a similar `If` statement to trap for that eventuality.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to mark it as answered when you can.